# SecurityManager for specific ThreadGroup

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm developing an opensource framework as microservices engine in java.
So, i have an Service class with many methods which can be called from any thread. To control the service threads, i want to guarantee what all threads related to the service will be created under a specific `ThreadGroup` only.

Thread A -> service.createNewThreadUnderCurrentThreadGroup() -> throw an exception from `SecurityManager`

Thread A -> service.createNewThreadUnderServiceThreadGroup() -> success

I am not an expert about `SecurityManager`s and `ThreadGroup`s. Maybe, i should to configure it using `ClassLoader`s? Or using custom security manager? Please, any suggestions? I know what it can be checked from the service implementation directly, but i want to guarantee what that implementation will not hack mechanism and will not create threads outside of the service `ThreadGroup`.

One more idea is to creating new thread under the service `ThreadGroup` everytime a service method was called, so guarantee what that method will be executed under the service `ThreadGroup` and so no threads outside. But it can complicate a lot the code, assumes what service method can throw an throwable.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`SecurityManager` is deprecated since java 17 ([1](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/411), [2](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/SecurityManager.html)), so it's better to avoid using it in new code.